# iOS inserting 3D models into Open GL Game

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I want to make my first 3D game. I decided to make in Open GL. I am using Apples code that comes whit the new Open GL Game project. I know how to import my own objects and manipulate them. I am wondering if someone can tell me where to find a good tutorial or knows how display the objects. For a fact i know that in the default project the both cubes are the same model displayed twice. Sadly i could not find where is the part that displays them and aplies different colors.

Answer (score 3):

> Sadly i could not find where is the part that displays them and aplies different colors.

This just tells you, that you need to learn the basics of OpenGL first.

We could highlight you the lines responsible, but all you'd see are "strange" assignments of attribute pointers, index arrays and weird things calls uniforms passed around.

Comment: actually i am learning from http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial and i was curious. Any others  tutorials would be helpful. thank you